# How to know what file is opened by an application at any time?

Tags: file

I'm new here, so I don't have the time to contribute before I ask for u guys' help, so pardon me for that.

I'm not sure if this can be done, but I would like to find out the opened file(s) of an application.

Here I don't mean the "internal" opened files, but are those that are opened by the end-user (either by invoking the handling app thru file-assoc, or explicitely inside the app). Think *.cs or *.vb files in Visual Studio (yeah I'm an MS guy) or text files in Notepad.

I've looked at "verbs" in the Win Shell MSDN doc, but it only mentions the invoking, and no way to inspect info of invoked verbs. I also looked at DDE, but it looks like a general purpose facility and does not fit into my case here.

I have to say that my situation is difficult to be solved by Googling because of the lack of unique key words, so this would definitely needs human attention :)

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. Are you in control of the application (i.e. are you developing it), or is it a closed application that you want to inspect?

Comment: How would the 'monitor' tool be able to differentiate between the files being opened by the application or the files opened by the user of the application? I don't think it's possible as described.

Comment: Well, I've looked at "Delphi - get what files are opened by an application", it mentions using the API proc NtQuerySystemInformation(), but I've looked at the docs, it's an OS internal function, and I'm not sure if it's good to use
There's also a WalkObject prototype app, but then I have to chew all source code lines, and I prefer not to go thru the pain of reading them...
BTW, I am a C# developer, P/Invoke is also ok for me

Comment: No, I would like to inspect external applications
for example, a stand-alone winform app 
(instead of a vba macro inside the word document)
inspecting a currently Microsoft Word instance

It is not necessary to have real-time notification
The monitoring app initiates the inspection

Comment: ("How would the 'monitor' tool be able to differentiate between the files being opened by the application or the files opened by the user of the application")

What I am thinking is that
there might be a supported (and non low-level) mechanism provided by windows
much like e.g. DDE etc

Answer (score 3):

If you want to inspect a running process for open handles, you can use [ProcessExplorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) or the command-line application [Handle](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx).

ProcessExplorer is essentially the Windows Task Monitor on steroids. It's a very useful tool in day-to-day computing, as well as process debugging. I highly recommend it.

Comment: I think the challenge here is that he wants only the files opened by the user using the software not any application initiated file opens, i.e. .docx not dll, temp files, etc.

Comment: You can filter for those requirements in Process Explorer.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you are a C# programmer, and want some code to do this.  As far as I know, there is no easy programming API to find out this information - it isn't the Win32 API, but rather the Windows internal API.  However, the SysInternals suite of command line utilities (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062.aspx) can be used to find out this information.

The application you want is called Handle.

There will be no differences to the OS between what you call "internal files" (presumably ones opened by the program without user involvement) and ones which the user deliberately used.  You will have to supply this information by specifying the extension of the file.  For instance, if you wanted to find all the word files open in Word, the command line you would need is:

handle -p winword.exe | find ".doc"

If writing an app in C#, you could use the following class to return a list of open documents which match your pattern (note this contains a form called ShowOpenAppFilesForm, with two text boxes **appExeNameTextBox** and **fileExtensionTextBox**, and a list box **openFileListBox**):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ShowOpenAppFiles
{
 public partial class ShowOpenAppFilesForm : Form
 {
  private const string HandlePath = @"D:\Development\SysInternals\SysinternalsSuite\Handle.exe";

  public ShowOpenAppFilesForm()
  {
   InitializeComponent();
  }


  private void showButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
   string[] fileExtensions = new string[1];
   fileExtensions[0] = fileExtensionTextBox.Text;
   openFileListBox.DataSource = Show(appExeNameTextBox.Text, fileExtensions);
  }

  private List<string> Show(string programExeName, string[] fileExtensions)
  {
   Process childProcess = new Process();
   ProcessStartInfo startInfo = childProcess.StartInfo;
   startInfo.FileName = HandlePath;
   startInfo.Arguments = " -p " + programExeName;
   startInfo.CreateNoWindow =false;
   startInfo.ErrorDialog = false;
   startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
   startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

   childProcess.Start();

   StreamReader stdOutput = childProcess.StandardOutput;

   List<string> fileNameList = new List<string>();

   while (!stdOutput.EndOfStream)
   {
    string line = stdOutput.ReadLine();
    for (int i = 0; i < fileExtensions.Length; i++)
    {
     if (line.Contains("." + fileExtensions[i]))
     {
      fileNameList.Add(line.Substring(21));
     }
    }
   }
   childProcess.WaitForExit();

   return fileNameList;
  }
 }
}
```

[Incidentally, DDE is mostly toast now.]

Comment: In python, there is a `psutil` module. It has a `Process.open_files()` function. But it get less info than the `Handle` app.

Comment: It seems like `Handle` app doesn't support utf-8. `psutil` module does.

Answer (score 0):

There is a utility found in SysInternals which can list the files opened by an application [Link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb545046.aspx) here

Comment: PsFile would be the one you are looking for

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to do so programmatically, so this might not be the right tool to me

Answer (score 0):

A quick one that only works for file-locking is a shell extension called [WhoLockMe](http://www.dr-hoiby.com/WhoLockMe/). It's not as powerful as some of the other tools here, but it's a context menu away in Windows explorer.